# Move GameObject in top left of other element

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine

Im' using unity 4.6.
I have an UI Panel and a GameObject (prefab)

This is my code :

```
//Retrieve the panel
RectTransform panel = this.GetComponent<RectTransform> ();

//Instantiate prefab and 
GameObject currentTile = Instantiate (tile.tilePrefab, Vector3.zero, 
                         Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
currentTile.transform.SetParent(transform);
```

So with this code, i can instantiate my Prefab and move into the panel.

But how can i move my prefab in top left of my panel (with a margin :) )? For now i move my prefab manually with 2 variables X Y.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If I understood right, you can create prefab with margin as you need and use

```
transform.SetParent(transform, false);
```